# How to setup access control for the user in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a users table where roles field contains **["ROLE_SUPERUSER"]**

Now I have two Urls:

- localhost:8000/api/en/login
- localhost:8000/api/en/test

When the user successfully logins, it generate a cookie. How can set the access control to the second URL where if the cookie is not set then this URL is not allowed.

I have added following lines to the `security.yaml` file

```
access_control:
 - { path: ^/api/{locale}, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
 - { path: ^/api/{locale}, roles: ROLE_SUPERUSER}
```

But this didn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firewall will take the first route that matches and apply the restriction.

One doesn't want to apply some firewall restrictions for login path, so it can be excluded from the list.

I'm not 100% sure if `{locale}` in firewall will work, unlike in the route description. However, you can use RegEx to define a rule on `^/api/<anything>/test` :

```
access_control:
 - { path: ^/api/.*?/test, roles: ROLE_SUPERUSER }
```

Comment: Thanks @Cid, it worked. One more question. I have many routes such as test. So what should be instead of test - { path: ^/api/.*?/*, roles: ROLE_SUPERUSER }

Comment: access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/.*?/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
        - { path: ^/api/.*?/*, roles: ROLE_SUPERUSER }

Answer (score 2):

In `access_control` first matching setting is taken. Because your patterns both match, all users will be `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`.
You have to use seperate paths/patterns for your firewall to authorize with diffrent roles:

```
access_control:
 - { path: ^/api/{locale}/secured, roles: ROLE_SUPERUSER}
 - { path: ^/api/{locale}, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

You can find more info in the docs:
[Symfony - How to restrict Firewalls to a Request](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/firewall_restriction.html)